# no visible @interface does not debug

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 -(IBAction)TakePhoto {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentedViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)ChooseExisting {
picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker2.delegate = self;
[picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentedViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imageview setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
  - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

When I try to run this app I the

```
[self presentedViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Gets highlighted in red saying No visible @interface for ViewController Declares the sector presentedviewcontroller:animated :completion :

My .h file is

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImagePickerController *picker2;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

}

- (IBAction)TakePhoto;
- (IBAction)ChooseExisting;
```

Comment: I think ur view is not child view of `UINavigationController`. try adding `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Comment: correct typo and try if it still doesn't work than see your base sdk should be 5 or + to use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `presentedViewController` instead of `presentViewController` on the line

```
[self presentedViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(in more than one place)